# It is possible to connect two xml's together

Tags: xml

I have some questions , because i am not good in XSLT...

For example, I have 3 types of xml from three companies

XML 1 (Company 1) file1.xml

```
<HotelList name="Company1">
   <Hotel><HotelCode>C1004</HotelCode>

                 <HotelName>Hotel 4</HotelName>

                <Price>100</Price>

   </Hotel>
    <Hotel><HotelCode>C1001</HotelCode>

                <HotelName>Hotel 1</HotelName>

                <Price>20</Price>

   </Hotel>
   <Hotel><HotelCode>C1003</HotelCode>

                <HotelName>Hotel 3</HotelName>

                <Price>15</Price>

   </Hotel>
   <Hotel><HotelCode>C1002</HotelCode></HotelList>

               <HotelName>Hotel 2</HotelName>

                <Price>10</Price>

   </Hotel>
```

XML 2  (Company 2) file2.xml

```
<HotelList name="Company2">
    <Hotel><HotelCode>C2002</HotelCode>

               <HotelName>Hotel Two</HotelName>

                <PriceList><Price>15</Price></PriceList>

   </Hotel>
   <Hotel><HotelCode>C2005</HotelCode>

                 <HotelName>Hotel Five</HotelName>

                 <PriceList><Price>100</Price></PriceList>

   </Hotel>
   <Hotel><HotelCode>C2003</HotelCode>

                <HotelName>Hotel Three</HotelName>

                <PriceList><Price>7</Price></PriceList>

   </Hotel>
   <Hotel><HotelCode>C2004</HotelCode>

                 <HotelName>Hotel Four</HotelName>

                <PriceList><Price>99</Price></PriceList>

   </Hotel>


   <Hotel><HotelCode>C2001</HotelCode>
</HotelList>

                <HotelName>Hotel One</HotelName>

                <PriceList><Price>10</Price></PriceList>



 </Hotel>
```

XML 3  (Company 3) file3.xml

```
<HotelList name="Company2">
    <Hotel><HotelCode>13 </HotelCode>

                <HotelName>Hotel One</HotelName>

                <Rates><PriceList><Price>11</Price></PriceList></Rates>

   </Hotel>
   <Hotel><HotelCode>23</HotelCode>

               <HotelName>Hotel Two</HotelName>

               <Rates><PriceList><Price>8</Price></PriceList></Rates>

   </Hotel>
     <Hotel><HotelCode>53</HotelCode>

                 <HotelName>Hotel Five</HotelName>

                <Rates><PriceList><Price>100</Price></PriceList></Rates>

   </Hotel>

  <Hotel><HotelCode>63</HotelCode>

                 <HotelName>Hotel Six</HotelName>

                <Rates><PriceList><Price>120</Price></PriceList></Rates>

   </Hotel>
  <Hotel><HotelCode>33</HotelCode>

                <HotelName>Hotel Three</HotelName>

               <Rates><PriceList><Price>7</Price></PriceList></Rates>

   </Hotel>
   <Hotel><HotelCode>43</HotelCode>

                 <HotelName>Hotel Four</HotelName>

               <Rates><PriceList><Price>85</Price></PriceList></Rates>

   </Hotel>


</HotelList>
```

1)   Here the xml, Hotel's ids are not in order way

2)      Hotel id and hotel names is not a constant one

3)      If hotel id is not constant, there is any need for create a sql table for keeping constant id? Some thing like this

```
HotelName             HotelCode          NewHotelName          NewHotelCode

Hotel 1                    C1001               Hotel-1                           1

Hotel 2                    C1002               Hotel-2                           2

Hotel 3                    C1003               Hotel-3                           3

Hotel 4                    C1004               Hotel-4                           4

Hotel One                C2001               Hotel-1                           1

Hotel Two                C2002               Hotel-2                           2

Hotel Three              C2003               Hotel-3                           3

Hotel Four                C2004               Hotel-4                           4

Hotel Five                 C2005               Hotel-5                           5

Hotel One                 13                    Hotel-1                           1

Hotel Two                 23                    Hotel-2                           2

Hotel Three               33                    Hotel-3                           3

Hotel Four                 43                    Hotel-4                           4

Hotel Five                  53                    Hotel-5                           5

Hotel Six                    63                    Hotel-6                          6
```

3)      My aim is that, to display less price hotels (with out duplicate) from these three xml’s

4)      I need the result is

```
Hotel Name: Hotel-1

Hotel Code: C2001

Hotel New Code: 1

Price :10



Hotel Name: Hotel-2

Hotel Code: 23

Hotel New Code: 2

Price :8



Hotel Name: Hotel-3

Hotel Code: C1003

Hotel New Code: 3

Price :7



Hotel Name: Hotel-4

Hotel Code: 43

Hotel New Code: 4

Price :85



Hotel Name: Hotel-5

Hotel Code: C2005

Hotel New Code: 5

Price :100



Hotel Name: Hotel-6

Hotel Code: 63

Hotel New Code: 6

Price :120
```

Comment: @Alex: Good grief, your post consists mostly of empty lines. Is that really necessary? Empty lines do not enhance readability, much to the contrary. Please take them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see [this reference](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/merge.html) for an example.